# Password Management : Hard coded password in html

Tags: html, security, passwords, fortify, hardcoded

Fortify lists outputs the following line as vulnerable to attack under the category - `Password Management : Hard coded Password`. Though I've not hard coded the password. Why is it showing that as a vulnerability, and how do I fix it?

```
txtPassword.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: What I thought was, Fortify shows this place just because of the variable name contains the word 'Password'. I tried renaming 'txtPassword' to 'txtPwd' in the html file and it seems to be working. Fortify doesn't show up the error in this place. But, I am looking for a better resolution here, if there are any. Somehow, just renaming the the variable name doesn't convince me enough to go with it.

Answer (score 6):

I do not have visibility to the internals, but it appears that as part of the 'Structural Analyzer', the Fortify tool searches for text that may indicate that there is a password stored.  It cannot tell if there is a password hard coded, but, based on a conversation with an HP Fortify consultant, Fortify leans toward flagging an issue if at all in doubt, allowing the person(s) remediating the audit information to determine if it is a vulnerability or not.

The following text example trigger a line of of code to be flagged my code base.

- Password
- password
- Passwd
- passwd

There are a couple of ways to remediate the issue and the correct one for your organization may depend on the work effort:

1. Mark the flagged issue as 'Not an Issue', indicating that this is a variable/control name and that a password is not hard coded in the code.
2. Rename the variable/control name to something that would not be flagged - txtPwd may be an option in this case.

Comment: Excellent answer. In some contexts, "pwd" is also searched for (but not all)

Comment: @DouglasHeld Thank you.  I thought I had seen 'pwd' flagged, but it did not shake out on my quick test.  Thanks for the info. Good to know.